# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'

Tags: asp-classic, error-handling, ado

ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

/down_see.asp, line 21

my code here:

```
Sorgu="Select * From tblNews"
Rs.Open Sorgu,bag,1

rs.Close
Set rs=Nothing

Set rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQL = "Select * From tblnews""
rs1.Open SQL,conn,1,3

rs1("hit")=rs1("hit")+1
rs1.update
```

what wrong ?

Comment: @mikeY I just edited the question, I didn't ask it. Sorry.

Comment: @mykroft It would help if I looked in the right place for the name of the OP.  Sorry.  LOL.

Answer (score 1):

rs("hit") is a string and not a number.  Cast it as a number.  Integer will do probably.

```
hit= Cint(rs1("hit"))+1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a double quote where there should be a single quote at the end of this line

**SQL = "Select * From tblnews""**

Answer (score 0):

You must use bag or conn if your database connection opened with bag you must use it.

```
Rs.Open Sorgu,bag,1

rs1.Open SQL,conn,1,3     
rs1.Open SQL,bag,1,3
```