# Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Tags: sql, asp-classic

This is the search-process.asp file, I have a main page with a search box that links to this and uses search terms to search my database.

```vbs
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>UNIBOOK - Your facebook alternative - but with no adverts..!</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/unibookStyle.css" />
<%@ Language=VBScript %>

<%

set conx=server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
conx.Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
conx.Open Server.Mappath("db/unibookv2.mdb")

set userRs=server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")

userRs.Open "SELECT * FROM ubuser WHERE usr_firstname LIKE '%" & request("searchinput") & "%' OR usr_lastname LIKE '%" & request("searchinput") & "%' ORDER BY '%" & request("orderlist") & "%' ",conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic

%>
<!-- #include FILE="include/header.asp") -->

<div id="container"><!-- start container -->


<h2>USER DATABASE</h2>

<!-- start of dynamic html page -->
<h2>ASP Search Results ordered by : <%=request("orderlist")%></h2>
<%="<b>Search string:</b> " & searchinput & "<br />"%>
<hr align="left" width="658" />

<%if NOT userRs.EOF Then%>

<!-- start of html table -->
    <table border="0" width="758" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

    <!-- create the first (heading) row in standard HTML -->
    <tr class="tableheading">
        <td><b>Usr_id</b></td><td><b>firstname</b></td><td>&nbsp;<b>lastname</b></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><b>Usr_id</b></td><td><b>firstname</b></td><td>&nbsp;<b>lastname</b></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<% counter=0 %>
    <%Do While Not userRs.EOF
    counter=counter+1
if ((counter mod 2)= 1) Then%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=userRs("usr_id") & "&nbsp;"%>
            </td>
            <td>

                <%=userRs("usr_firstname") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=userRs("usr_lastname") %>
            </td>

    <%else%>


            <td>
                <!-- display the name of the mountain -->
                <%=userRs("usr_id") & "&nbsp;"%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- some comment here -->
                <%=userRs("usr_firstname") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=userRs("usr_lastname") %>
            </td>

        </tr>
<%end if%>
<%userRs.MoveNext
LOOP%>


</table>

<%else%>
    <!-- remember to provide a message if the search is not successful -->
    <h3>Sorry your search was unsuccessful, please retry</h3>
<%end if%>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr align="left" width="658">

<input type="button" value="< Back to Search Page" OnClick="top.location='default.asp'">

<!-- #include FILE="include/sidebar.asp") -->
</div><!-- end main page content -->

<%
' tidy up any ASP objects used to free web server resources...
userRs.close
set userRs=nothing
set conx=nothing
%>
<!-- #include FILE="include/footer.asp") -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error and am not sure if it is the SQL or ASP

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'
>   Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
>
> /student/s0190204/part2/search-process.asp, line 17

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9' : Arguments are of the wrong type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428704/adodb-recordset-error-800a0bb9-arguments-are-of-the-wrong-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including the definitions for `adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic` etc... Its usually in a file called adovbs.inc, but you could add them to other include files in your page..

Answer (score 1):

An unterminated string constant can be caused by an apostrophe in the search input.  That is one of the many problems that can be solved by using query parameters.

Comment: This is by far the most sensible answer here! Consider using `ADODB.Command` object and building parametrised queries. Without it you are open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).