# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'

Tags: web-applications, asp-classic

I'm learning classic ASP and cannot seem to get my first file to work properly. I'm attempting to link an html form to an .accdb. Any advice?

```vb
'Declare variables
dim formdate, jsia, jsga, yvcia, yvgia, query, errorFlag

'Collect data from form
formdate = Request.Form("date")
jsia = Request.Form("jsia")
jsga = Request.Form("jsga")
yvcia = Request.Form("yvcia")
yvcga = Request.Form("yvcga")

'SQL for Query
query = "INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES (formdate, jsia, jsga, yvcia, yvcga);"

'Create and open connection to database
'On Error Resume Next
set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
Connect.Open(Server.Mappath("database.accdb"))

'Create recordset
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

'Open recordset run query in database 
rs.Open query, Connect, adOpenStatic, adOpenOptimistic

'Display message
Response.Write("<h1>Your form has been received. Thank you.</h1>")

'Close recordset and database connection
rs.close
Connect.close
```

Comment: Your need build your query with the form values. Also you need use ado command or the connection to run insert statement.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428704/adodb-recordset-error-800a0bb9-arguments-are-of-the-wrong-type).

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error with your LockTypeEnum value.

Change this line...

```
rs.Open query, Connect, adOpenStatic, adOpenOptimistic
```

...to...

```
rs.Open query, Connect, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

That might fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my namesake's suggestion in the other answer, you'll need to change the query to

```
query = "INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES ('"&formdate&"', '"&jsia&"', '"&jsga&"', '"&yvcia&"', '"&yvcga&"');"
```

The single quotes are there because you need to put string and datetime values inside single quotes in a SQL query, the ampersands and double quotes are there because that's what you need to do to concatenate your variables into your insert query.

Once you have it working I strongly recommend you look at ways of protecting your insert against SQL injection attacks.

I also recommend following the steps in this page to enable friendly error messages - they'll help you determine what in your script isn't working.

http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses, I actually had quite a few errors.

I did not declare variables for my objects (rs and Connect).

Also, I did not link my page to my common folder where my .inc files are located.

Thanks again!