# getting error ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9' Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to bind data to my page from database the code is given below

```vb
 Dim oCon, pages, Rec, DisplayNum, i, page, SQL, ipage, z, MaxRows
    Set QGetList = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
    'QGetList.PageSize = MaxRows
    'QGetList.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
'Set QGetProgramItem = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            SQL =   " SELECT ModelRow, SeriesRow, ModelCode, Item.* FROM tblSPCMaster_Item Item " &_
                    " LEFT OUTER JOIN viewModelSeries VM on VM.vch_ModelName = Item.vModelName AND VM.modelcode = Item.vModelCode " &_
                    " WHERE iSPCMasterID = '"  & Request.querystring("PID") & "' ORDER BY ModelRow, SeriesRow, Item.iSeq"
            QGetList.Open SQL, dpconn, 1
    ipage = QGetList.PageCount

    
    if QGetList.EOF OR QGetList.BOF Then
        x = 1
    else
        if page = 0 or page > ipage Then
            QGetList.AbsolutePage = ipage
        else
            QGetList.AbsolutePage = page
        end if  
    end if
    
    
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Stock_Inventory_Management_Export_" & Year(now) & Month(now) & day(now) & hour(now) & minute(now) & ".xls"
```

i am getting error:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

what i am missing i am not getting please help me

Comment: This is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attack.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn is right this is poor practice and will leave you wide open to SQL Injection attacks. The error though is caused by incorrect parameters, where is `dpconn` variable, is it a `ADODB.Connection` object or a connection string? If it's an object did you call `.Open()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9' : Arguments are of the wrong type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428704/adodb-recordset-error-800a0bb9-arguments-are-of-the-wrong-type)

Comment: Code looks reasonable and I just added it to some of mine and ran it after providing the missing variables and changing the SQL of couse, and it runs. However, if I set the value of page to -1 I can get the  800a0bb9 error. My error output gives me the line number - did yours? What was it? Anyway check the logic for the paging.

Comment: Regarding the heat you are drawing over SQL injection risk - google for sql injection and learn about it. As a hint, you need to use parameter-driven database stored procedures and avoid building queries with strings supplied by the user. There is more to consider so do the research.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat there's plenty of examples on this site alone.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```vb
QGetList.Open SQL, dpconn, 1
```

For the first argument, it expects an `Command` object. You gave it a string.

Fix your SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: thanks but i am new can you correct it whats wrong if possible thanks in advance

Comment: While true this is not the cause of the error. The `ADODB.Recordset` object can happily take a SQL statement string as the *source* argument as well as a `ADODB.Command` object. See [Open Method (ADO Recordset)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Lankymart I can confirm that the param for connection here can be a string.